# Executing GP Task for JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-mapping, arcgis-rest-api, zip-codes, geoprocessing-service

I recently started using JavaScript API in attempt to construct a web app. After taking a recent ESRI online course, I thought I had some base knowledge on how to do this.

This geoprocessing service I'm using from our development server is supposed to take an input of a ZipCode and in turn display delivery routes associated with said ZipCode.

I've looked at some sample code on the ArcGIS Javascript API help site and cannot figure out how to execute this with its parameters.

If anyone has any insight or where I can look for documentation on how I can initiliaze this task and make it appear on my WebMap, I'd be forever indebted.

Thanks!

Below is the REST services page for the geoprocessor.

```
Execution Type: esriExecutionTypeSynchronous 

Parameters: 
Parameter: ZIP 
Data Type: GPString 
Display Name ZIP 
Description: ZIP code or list of comma, space, or tab delimited 5 digit ZIP codes 
Direction: esriGPParameterDirectionInput 
Default Value: 38138 
Parameter Type: esriGPParameterTypeRequired 
Category: 

Parameter: Rte_Box 
Data Type: GPString 
Display Name Rte_Box 
Description: R = carrier route, B = PO Box 
Direction: esriGPParameterDirectionInput 
Default Value: R 
Parameter Type: esriGPParameterTypeOptional 
Category: 

Parameter: Output_Feature_Class 
Data Type: GPFeatureRecordSetLayer 
Display Name Output_Feature_Class 
Description: Geometry and delivery stats for routes that meet search criteria 
Direction: esriGPParameterDirectionOutput 
Default Value:
Geometry Type: esriGeometryPolyline 
HasZ: false 
HasM: false 
Spatial Reference: 102100  (3857) 

Fields:
OBJECTID ( type: esriFieldTypeOID , alias: OBJECTID )
ZIP_CRID ( type: esriFieldTypeString , alias: ZIP_CRID , length: 13 )
ZIP_CODE ( type: esriFieldTypeString , alias: ZIP_CODE , length: 5 )
CRID_ID ( type: esriFieldTypeString , alias: CRID_ID , length: 4 )
CRID_IND ( type: esriFieldTypeString , alias: CRID_IND , length: 1 )
CRID_NBR ( type: esriFieldTypeString , alias: CRID_NBR , length: 3 )
CITY_STATE ( type: esriFieldTypeString , alias: CITY_STATE , length: 32 )
BUS_CNT ( type: esriFieldTypeDouble , alias: BUS_CNT )
TOT_CNT ( type: esriFieldTypeDouble , alias: TOT_CNT )
DROP_CNT ( type: esriFieldTypeDouble , alias: DROP_CNT )
RES_CNT ( type: esriFieldTypeDouble , alias: RES_CNT )
DROPSHIP_KEY ( type: esriFieldTypeString , alias: DROPSHIP_KEY , length: 6 )
FACILITY_NAME ( type: esriFieldTypeString , alias: FACILITY_NAME , length: 35 )
LESS_THAN200_IND ( type: esriFieldTypeString , alias: LESS_THAN200_IND , length: 1 )
FAUX_IND ( type: esriFieldTypeString , alias: FAUX_IND , length: 1 )
LT_200_IND ( type: esriFieldTypeString , alias: LT_200_IND , length: 1 )
DS_KEY ( type: esriFieldTypeString , alias: DS_KEY , length: 7 )
FAC_NAME ( type: esriFieldTypeString , alias: FAC_NAME , length: 35 )
Shape_Length ( type: esriFieldTypeDouble , alias: Shape_Length )
Features: None.


Parameter Type: esriGPParameterTypeRequired 
Category:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the documentation for the [GeoProcessor](http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jshelp/intro_gp_overview.html).

Basically, you will create a new geoprocessor object like this:
`gp = new esri.tasks.Geoprocessor("http://YourServer/ArcGIS/rest/services/foo/GPServer/bar");`

Then you will need to create a parameter object, with the two required parameters. for this, I'm assuming you will need to take the user's input and put in the zip code, as the RTE_box if required.
so your code can be somethinglike this:

```
var zipcode=<input from user>;
var type=<RTE input from user>;

var params={"ZIP":zipcode,"Rte_Box":type };
```

You will then call the execute function on the geoprocessor, also passing in the callback function, like this:

```
//your callback function is called onResults
gp.execute(params, onResults);
```

In your onResults function, you will get the resulting featureset, which you can then draw on the map as graphics.

There are several samples available, like this one: [Service area task](http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/gp_servicearea.html)

Comment: So if im using an ArcGIS basemap, and i get the onResults featureset, do I need to create a graphic layer or a feature layer to place the results in? Or should it display on the basemap itself.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a graphics layer. You can add it to the map using `map.graphics.add(feature);` like in the sample linked above.

Comment: To clarify though, map.graphics is the default graphics layer. Further graphics layers could be added for organization, if needed, and you would add features to another an additional graphic layer in the same way.